# Python : Regex capturing genric for 3 cases.

Tags: python, regex, findall

Hi Anyone help me imporve my not working regular expresion.

***Strings Cases:***

> 1) 120 lbs and is intended for riders ages *8 years and up*.    **#catch : 8 years and up**
>
> 2) 56w x 28d x 32h inches  recommended for hobbyists  recommended for ages *12 and up*. **#catch : 12 and up**
>
> 3) 4 users recorded speech for effective use  language tutor pod measures 11l x 9w x 5h inches  recommended for ages *6 and above*.   **#catch : 6 and above**

I want a **genric regular expression** which works perfectly for all the three string.

> My regular expression is :
>
> > **\b\d+[\w+\s]*?(?:\ban[a-z]*\sup\b|\ban[a-z]*\sabove\b|\ban[a-z]*\sold[a-z]*\b|\b&\sup)**

But it is not working quite well. If anyone can provide me a  ***generic regular expression*** which works ***for all 3 cases***. **I am using python re.findall()**

Anyone? could Help?

Comment: Try [`\b\d+\s*(?:\w+\s+)?an[a-z]*\s+(?:up|above|old[a-z]*)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/pC7rL3/4).

Comment: Hope this helps, `re.search(r'(?is)ages\s*(.*?)\.$',s).group(1)`

Comment: If your examples illustrate all possible strings (but I fear they don't ;) you could do it as simple as `\d+[^\d]*$`. [See it at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gX5cC4/2). It matches the last number and everything after it. Or a little bit more sophisticated - making sure it's preceded by `age` - [here](https://regex101.com/r/gX5cC4/3).

Comment: Actually, it is not at all clear what *generic* pattern will work for you since there are just 3 examples and no specs are provided. One can only guess what you really need.

Comment: \d+[^\d]*$ was a saviour thanks :-D. clasG. I dont know why people give negative point over here. I had a problem i questioned. thats all. Thanks people for answering. Good day.!

Answer (score 2):

Make it a habit and start with verbose regular expressions:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'''
    ages\                                # look for ages
    (\d+(?:\ years)?\ and\ (?:above|up)) # capture a digit, years eventually
                                         # and one of above or up
''', re.VERBOSE)

string = '''
1) 120 lbs and is intended for riders ages 8 years and up. #catch : 8 years and up
2) 56w x 28d x 32h inches recommended for hobbyists recommended for ages 12 and up. #catch : 12 and up
3) 4 users recorded speech for effective use language tutor pod measures 11l x 9w x 5h inches recommended for ages 6 and above. #catch : 6 and above
'''

matches = rx.findall(string)
print(matches)
# ['8 years and up', '12 and up', '6 and above']
```

---

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/vsSu4w) as well as on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/eK6bI0/1).

Answer (score 1):

(As the suggestion I made in a comment appears to have been what you wanted, I offer it as an answer.)

If your examples illustrate all possible strings (but I fear they don't ;) you could do it as simple as

```
\d+[^\d]*$
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gX5cC4/2).

It matches the last number, and everything after it.

Or a little bit more sophisticated - making sure it's preceded by age - [here](https://regex101.com/r/gX5cC4/3)